# Align-Area for Fancybox to center

Tags: fancybox, alignment

we have a left oriented website with wallpaper commercial. So the center of the page is pushed to the left. It would great if we could define a area/point where the fancybox align to.

like: 
padding: 100px 300px 0 0;

topRatio would not help for this.

Thanks for help,
Ulli

Answer (score 1):

You can push the box using option "margin" - http://jsfiddle.net/jftDF/